# Python pandas Google finance international stocks - looking for way to get international stocks price history with Google

Tags: python, pandas

This works: domestic stocks

```
gticker='NYSE:IBM'
import pandas.io.data as web
dfg = web.DataReader(gticker, 'google', '2013/1/1', '2014/3/1')
```

This does not: international stocks

```
gticker='HKG:0700'
import pandas.io.data as web
dfg = web.DataReader(gticker, 'google', '2013/1/1', '2014/3/1')
```

even though for both, you can go to the "Historical prices" link and see historical data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: People, no idea why this was closed, question is very specific with the right sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataReader for google wants to download a csv file. So for 'goog' it requests the following URL which fetches the csv file:

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=GOOG&startdate=Jan+1%2C+2013&enddate=Mar+1%2C+2014&output=csv

This is true for all the domestic stocks (like IBM). But for 'HKG:0700' it requests:

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=HKG%3A0700&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2014&enddate=Mar+01%2C+2014&output=csv

and that produces a 'The requested URL was not found on this server.' error. You can look at the historical data at:

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=HKG%3A0700&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2014&enddate=Mar+01%2C+2014

But it doesn't look like you can get a csv file.

You see what it is doing pandas/io/data.py when it creates the URL:

```
# www.google.com/finance/historical?q=GOOG&startdate=Jun+9%2C+2011&enddate=Jun+8%2C+2013&output=csv
url = "%s%s" % (_HISTORICAL_GOOGLE_URL,
                urlencode({"q": sym,
                           "startdate": start.strftime('%b %d, ' '%Y'),
                           "enddate": end.strftime('%b %d, %Y'),
                           "output": "csv"}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But i guess i'm asking how to use pandas to get international stocks with Google.

Answer (score 3):

It seems Google Finance only support CSV download for US and UK market, as the link "Download to spreadsheet" under "Historical chart" only appears for stocks listed in these two markets in the following example:

HSBC stock listed in UK
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=LON%3AHSBA

HSBC stock listed in US
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSE%3AHSEA

HSBC stock listed in Hong Kong
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=HKG%3A0005

Comment: In addition to working for the UK (e.g. LSE:ULVR) it also works for Germany (e.g. ETR:HEN) and Switzerland (e.g. VTX:NESN). It doesn't seem to work for France (e.g. EPA:BN) and Spain (e.g. BME:ITX).